# If $A-B = B-A$ what can we say about sets $A$ and $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I know this was a question that was previously asked, but what I'm asking isn't for the answer, I know what the answer is, and I know of another method of proving this. I'm wondering if my own rough work is correct because I showed them what amounted to my intuitive method of doing it to someone else and they said that the reasoning was somewhat "sketch", though admittedly it was not as structured. Below the rough work of my intended proof is outlined.
[image]

Comment: First assume $A$ and $B$ have no common intersection. Now $A-B$ is just $A$ and $B-A$ is just $B$. $A-B = B-A$ simply means $A=B$. Now assume they have some common intersection. Here $A-B = B-A$ says that leaving out the intersection they are the same, and intersection anyway being the same you have $A=B$

Comment: I get that, however, I am wondering if my method is correct, rather than asking for a method of doing so. Because my rough work seems to parallel your suggestion for a proof premised on the assumption of a common intersection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a really 'rough' proof indeed since it makes little sense to say something like:

$x \in A \cap B' = x \in A' \cap B$

because you are now putting an equality sign between two statements, rather than between two sets.

So, better would be:

$A-B=B-A$

$\Rightarrow A \cap B' = B \cap A'$

$\Rightarrow A - A \cap B = B - A \cap B$

$\Rightarrow A=B$

However, this 'proof' still suffers from a big problem. In the last step, you 'cross out' the '$-A \cap B$' on both sides, and the thinking seems to be:

If $A - X= B-X$, then we can cross out the '$-X$' part, and get to $A=B$

But note: that is not true in general!

For example, if $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, and $X=\{1,2\}$, then $A-X=B-X=\emptyset$, but clearly $A\neq B$

So, you really can't do this kind of 'crossing out' when it comes to sets!

Or at the very least: you have to be very careful when 'crossing out', because you can only do this under certain conditions .... which, as it so happens, apply in this particular case ... but you would have needed to point that out to make the proof a proper proof.

Comment: Alright, this is the type of answer I was going for, this makes a lot of the errors with my thinking process a bit clearer. Thanks a lot, now I'll move on to attempting an alternative proof strategy.

Comment: @MurkMurk You're welcome! And good luck! :)

Comment: Okay but coming back to this, however, is crossing out the intersection wrong since the intersection itself is completely contained in A and B, that is, that the intersection is a subset of both sets? Is that what I should point out to rectify my proof? I get that getting into the habit of crossing things that are not common is a problem. But is there a counterexample such that crossing out C of an expression A-C = B-C where C is a subset of both A and B leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @MurkMurk Right, when $C$ is a subset of both $A$ and $B$, then the crossing out is ok.